# How to insert data to a sqlite database with table name as variable

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite, jdbc, odbc

I would like to insert data into my sqlite data base but with a variable as the name of the table where the data should be entered.

```
try {

            Random rand = new Random();
            uniqueID = rand.nextInt(9998) + 1; //Generates a random number from 1 - 9999 inclusively
            String dateStart = day1.getText() + "/" + month1.getText() + "/" + year1.getText();
            String dateEnd = day2.getText() + "/" + month2.getText() + "/" + year2.getText();
            String projectN = projectName.getText();
            String addr = address.getText();
            //String engineerN = engineerName.getText();
            //String engineerP = engineerPassword.getText();

            Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
            conn2.setAutoCommit(false);


            PreparedStatement ps = conn2.prepareStatement("insert into "My table name" (uniqueid,name,address,startingdate,estcompletion) values(?,?,?,?,?,?)");
            ps.setInt(1, uniqueID);
            ps.setString(2, projectN);
            ps.setString(3, addr);
            ps.setString(4, dateStart);
            ps.setString(5, dateEnd);
            //ps.setString(6, engineerN);

            ps.execute();

            ps.close();
            conn2.commit();
            conn2.close();
           } 
    catch ( Exception e1) {
             System.err.println( e1.getClass().getName() + ": " + e1.getMessage() );
             System.exit(0);
           }
        }
    }
public String JJI() {
    return projectName.getText();

}
}
```

"My table name" in the prepared statement is the place where I want to put my table name getting it from projectName.getText(); at the end. The user enters projectname.getText in another class. 
Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Store your table name in a String variable (how you like): `String tableName = "users";`
2. Make a query variable that contains your SQL query:

`String query = "insert into '" + tableName + "' (uniqueid,name,address,startingdate,estcompletion) values(?,?,?,?,?,?)";`

3. If you would like to have variables to insert, replace the "?" with your variable names as you have done in your code:

   `ps.setInt(1, uniqueID);
   ps.setString(2, projectN);
   ps.setString(3, addr);
   ps.setString(4, dateStart);
   ps.setString(5, dateEnd);`
4. Execute the query:

`PreparedStatement ps = conn2.prepareStatement(query);
ps.execute();`

Comment: Your third point (to concatenate values into a query) is extremely bad form, it encourages SQL injection. The original solution was already the right one in that respect.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel You're extremely right, my apologies. Edited.

Comment: @SkibRs see updated answer as a reaction to the strong argument from Mark.